# Is there a browser for Windows that supports tab isolation like Safari in private mode?

Tags: windows, web-browser, privacy

In Safari, while browsing using a private window, you can log in to a service then open a new tab and go to the same service and log in to a separate account. This same concept works for carts (i.e. 2 separate tabs of the same website with different carts) or anything else that stores session data.

Is there a browser for Windows that supports the same idea? Safari is no longer supported on Windows and both Chrome and Firefox share session data across all private tabs and windows.

I did find a [similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19817/is-there-a-browser-which-supports-isolating-tabs), but it was asked over 4 years ago and proposed solutions required extensions to be installed

Answer (score 1):

[Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)/[Waterfox](https://www.waterfox.net/) support something called [Multi-Account Containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers) which can be enabled by a [config change](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers#w_for-advanced-users) or an [official extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) installation.

I personally use it together with the [Temporary Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/)** extension set to automatic, so unless specified, every tab is a completely separate browser session.

** If you use Waterfox, temporary containers automatic mode requires a [manual hack](https://github.com/stoically/temporary-containers/issues/335#issuecomment-560133655).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox.

It is a builtin Firefox feature, does not require add-ons.

[image]

You need to start Firefox with the `--ProfileManager --no-remote` command line flags.

To set it up, read this: [How to add command line options to a shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/29569/how-to-add-command-line-options-to-shortcut)

Comment: While this is an option, I recommend you check out Multi-Account Containers for a much more convenient solution (see my [answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/81067/76723))

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Ghost Browser](https://alternatives-magazine.com/ghost-browser/)** that fulfills your tab isolation requirement. Because Ghost Browser is specially designed for multi-login purposes. Each time you open a new tab, you can put it into a new Session. Newly tab has separate tab colors so you can easily distinguish among them.